# Flex container grows over its items max-width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have flex containers that are next to each other and I would like to have items in those containers to grow and shrink in the same way.
I sort of got it working except for the case when there are too few items in one of the containers to shrink its elements. My current problem is that flex containers are growing over its items max-width sum(first case shown in screenshot down below).

```
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">1</div>
  </div>
</div>

.main-container {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  
  /*irrelevant*/
  border-radius: 0.75rem;
  background-color: #fef3c7;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  
  /*irrelevant*/
  border-radius: 0.75rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 24rem;
  max-width: 30rem;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  
  /*irrelevant*/
  background-color: rgba(245,158,11,1);
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
  color: #FFF;
  height: 4rem;
  border-radius: 0.75rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
 /*irrelevant*/
.main-container .container:nth-child(2) .item {
  background-color: rgba(59,130,246,1);
}
```

[Here is the CodePen](https://codepen.io/theaksis/pen/poRddXZ)

The correct behavior would be that all items in all containers will shrink to their min-width before eventually overflowing if there is not enough space, and grow to the same size when there is space for it.

My MS Paint "drawing" will probably explain the problem better (click to zoom):

[image: Problem]

btw Items have to be inside separate containers for Backend+JS reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More I read about the CSS, I found out that there are lot of `display` options. When changing `.container` display to `contents` it works just perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `flex: 1 1 auto` to `flex: 1 1 1` otherwise it'll grab all available space seemingly past your max width.

Comment: Thank @ZedRei, this is one of the thing that I tried. It sort of works, but the side-effect is that items won't grow to their max-width when there is a space for it, they will be stuck at min-width.

Comment: I changed main.container to 0 1 1 and the container and item to 1 1 0. Individual items seemed to grown to their max.

Comment: Thanks again @ZedRei I wasn't sure which one you meant for the ".container" so I tried both https://i.imgur.com/wy5TM70.png As you can see in the first one it does grow to the max-width but the gap between containers is still there, in the second one there is no gap but items stay at their min. Anyway thanks for you time :)